# Z Order issue with transparency with Direct2D1

Tags: directx, transparency, directx-11, direct2d, sharpdx

While the overall process of my video game is quite good, I stumpled upon a problem. It may be a simple one, but I am unable to solve it at the moment.

I am using SharpDX with Direct2D1 for creating my user interface. I created several controls so far and some controls are composed out of other controls and some controls have sub-controls. For example, a window in my user interface has always a close button, a control for the border and one for the content. A list box control can have several controls as list items, etc.

This works well most of the time. However, I have some troubles when transparency is involved.

**Example 1**

I have a semi-transparent border around my windows and I want to display a text on top of this border. It's easy to see, that the transparent border color affects the color of the text.

**Example 2**

I have a rectangular background with a solid black color. After rendering this rectangle, I draw a bitmap which contains mostly nothing (= big transparent areas). When I run the game, I see the non-transparent regions on top of the black background, which is perfect. However, if I draw another bitmap right after the first one, it is drawn behind the background (solid black rectangle) and therefore not visible.

How can I control the z order? Anything is welcome!

Comment: Shot in the dark ... call `ID2D1RenderTarget::Flush()` to enforce a rigid rendering order? If that works, this sounds to me like some kind of bug in Direct2D.

Comment: Sounds like there is a possible issue with alpha mode. Are you using D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_IGNORE by any chance? Try D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED.

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot to answer! I solved this problems after a few days. I developped several custom controls for my user interface and one of them rendered its sub-components in the wrong order. This caused my z order issues!